# php form not submitting using ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

If i comment this code, then form submits.PLease tell me the error.This is the form

Comment: Check your JS console. There is likely a js error that's causing it to fail which is preventing the form from submitting. But since you are submitting with ajax, you probably want to `return false;` to prevent the form from actually submitting after your code runs.

Comment: show more from your code! you talking about a form and php, and only show us javascript code? plus, there is no such thing as "php forms", forms in web development are always `html` - forms.